# DOM:Permission denied while adding the screen share feature in electron js and angular desktop and web app using Navigator.mediaDevice.getUserDevices

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, desktop-application, navigator

while using the code

```
    const stream = await navigatorStub.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            audio: false,
            video:{
                displaySurface: 'desktop',
                logicalSurface: true,
                cursor: true,
                width: 1280,
                height: 720
            }
    });
```

I am trying to access the display to add a screen sharing feature in the electron js and angular app but getting the

> **Error:** DOM:Exception Permission denied

I want to add screen sharing feature in electron js and angular js to share the screen with `WebRtc`

Comment: the issue is now solved I just needed to change the name of the method getDisplayMedia to getUserMedia and it worked for me.

Comment: getUserMedia is used for Camera and audio, how come it solved to you for screensharing?